# Css в IE 8 без DOCTYPE

Tags: internet-explorer, doctype, css

Есть старый(очень, лет 10) сайт, на котором не указан DOCTYPE, добавить его нет возможности, т.к. всё полетит. Подскажите пожалуйста какой-нибудь источник, рассказывающий о поведении стилей в ie 8 без доктайпа, если такие есть

Comment: Объясните причину нет возможности добавить DOCTYPE?

Comment: > добавить его нет возможности, т.к. всё полетит.

Comment: писалось очень давно, мало того, что всё переделывать придёться, есть js/css фичи, которые с ним не работают, но ОЧЕНЬ нужны

Comment: мой совет - переписать стили для сайта с ДОБАВЛЕНИЕМ ДОКТАЙПА (если сайт не большой)

https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Источников море, стоит лишь погуглить "css ie8-only hack"
[1](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/), [2](http://dynamicweblab.com/2013/04/best-ways-to-detect-ie-browser/), [3](http://my.opera.com/dbloom/blog/2009/03/11/css-hack-for-ie8-standards-mode). Однако, от имени всего сообщества верстальщиков и прочих веб-технологов прошу сказать клиенту, что тут крайне необходимо переверстать под новые технологии и объяснить ему, зачем это нужно. Все к этому приходят, и я когда-то пришёл, и вы... пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

> рассказывающий о поведении стилей в ie
> 8

Включается так называемый "quirks mode". 
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html - тут довольно подробно и не только об этом.
Внизу таблица, которая показывает что будет работать, а что не очень.